# Pigeonhole principle to prove distance between two players

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

An NFL playing field is 360 ft by 160 ft. Prove that during an NFL game:

(a) Two of the 22 players are within 75 ft of each other.

(b) Four of the 22 players are within 50 yards of each other.

My question is can I divide the field into squares of 50 and 75 ft so I can use the pigeonhole principle as a proof? Is the proof that simple or is it more complex?

Comment: Using squares, be sure to look at the diagonal, not the sidelength.  For the first question, you can't use squares of side length $75$ because the diagonal is $75\times \sqrt 2$.

Comment: Also:  it's not immediately clear to me how you intend to arrange those $22$ squares.  You have to cover the field...

Comment: I was actually going to divide the each side by 75ft and 50yd respectively using a ceiling function so that each square is equal to or in most cases less than my desired distance. However, you do raise a good point about making sure the length of the hypotenuse in each of the boxes is less than or equal to 50yd or 75ft.

Comment: As I say, it's no use taking squares of side length $75$ because the diagonal is too long.  (you could have two points in the same square which are further than $75$ apart).  Now,  to make the diagonal $75$ you need the side length around $53$ and $\frac {160}{53} \approx  3$ and $\frac {360}{53}\approx 7$ so it's very, very close.  Not clear to me that it works.

Comment: You might do better with rectangles of diagonal $75$...or, if necessary, regular hexagons.

Comment: Just wrote it out...rectangles work.  Squares of side length $\frac {75}{\sqrt 2}\approx 53.033$ don't quite work.  But you can stretch them a bit (keeping the diagonal constant) and get a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going with a diagonal of 75 ft and 50 yds then I derived the other sides using trig and took the ceiling function to get a whole number of squares. Thank you for your help, I did consider that two players standing on opposite sides of the hypotenuse would be great than 75 ft given my initial proposal.

Comment: As I say, I can't see how to do it with squares.  Rectangles work:  if you take rectangles with width $\frac {160}3$ and length $\frac {360}7$ you can exactly cover the field with $3\times 7 = 21$ of them and the diagonal is $<75$.  Good thing...the hexagon tiling is more efficient but a lot harder to calculate with.